# How to get all RecordType names as list of string in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, recordtype

I am trying to retrieve names of all the RecordTypes of Account Object in salesforce. I am getting error with the soql query. I found this query on the web.

```
strQuery = 'SELECT Name, SobjectType FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType=\'Account\'';
        List<RecordType> lstRecordType = Database.query(strQuery);
```

This is returning a RecordType list. How I can get the names of the recordType only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through them? ;)

```
List<String> names = new List<String>();
for(RecordType rt : [SELECT Name FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Account']){
    names.add(rt.Name);
}
System.debug(names);
```